# How to fix PyCharm skeleton generation problem?

Tags: linux, pycharm, fedora

When I try to run PyCharm on my Fedora 31 VM I have error codes like that:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2020-02-28 10:44:10,339 [  18756]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - Some skeletons failed to generate 
2020-02-28 10:44:10,339 [  18756]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - libdnf._ 
2020-02-28 10:44:10,339 [  18756]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - pcardext
```

And my IDE after this is unreadable - I can't see anything on it - it's just a black window with random words on it.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Could you please make a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

This  happened to me if I moved the extracted folder to `/opt`.
Running it from the Downloads folder seemed to be ok.

Alternatively you can start it with `sudo ./pycharm.sh`